# In Win81+ non-dpi aware process, figure out scale factor

Tags: winapi, windows-8.1, resolution

I'm having an issue in that I am coding for a non-dpi aware process, until a bug fix lands.

So for now I need to do a work around. My thought is this: figure out the scale up factor, and give my elements width/height scaled down by that much.

So right now I am drawing a canvas that is full width and height of second monitor, it s `1920 x 1080` (WxH). But visuaully (as measured by photoshop after screenshot) it is coming out to be `2880 x 1620`. This is a scale up factor of 1.5 (2880 divided by 1920 or 1620 divided by 1080).

I tried getting dpi with methods of `GetDeviceCaps` and `EnumDisplaysettings` but all of them returned that of the primary monitor (note: `EnumDisplaySettings` sets `dmLogPixels` which I think is DPI to 0 if I do `EnumDisplaySettings` with constnat of `ENUM_REGISTRY_SETTINGS` so I had to use `ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS`).

The only method i found that returns differently is `GetDpiForMonitor` with `MONITOR_DPI_TYPE` constnat of `MDT_Angular_DPI` or `MDT_Raw_DPI`, if I use `MDT_Effective_DPI` it gives that of the primary monitor.

So now this is my results of running `GetDpiForMonitor`:

[image]

None of the secondary values divided by the primary are giving me a scale up factor 1.5. Is there anyway to get this scale factor?

Thanks

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn384110%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant !

Comment: @HansPassant my way using `EnumDisplaySettings` was cool if the DPI was set to default. If the user goes to panel and does "make text larger" it will not work properly. So I wanted to use your `LogicalToPhysicalPointForPerMonitorDPI` function but for that it needs the `hwnd` to a window. Is there a way I can pass it a `hmon` of a monitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had an idea nad it works I am getting the scaled height/width with any of the three methods outlined in my question here: [Improper width and height for second monitor from GetMonitorInfo and GetDeviceCaps](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30117988/1828637)

- `GetDeviceCaps` on `hdcScreen` or
- `GetMonitorInfo` or
- `EnumDisplayMonitors`

Then I divide it by the width/height from `EnumDisplaySettings`.

This is the only way I found how, is there any other way? Can the experts please verify.